# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

estoy tratando de crear un archivo json de forma dynamica en el dispositivo, el archivo se crea correctamente, pero cuando trato de hacer el jsonDecode me arroja este error.

El error es este:

```
The following LateError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: HomeState#853db):
LateInitializationError: Field 'fileContent' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Home
package:json_storage/main.dart:101
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      HomeState.fileContent (package:json_storage/main.dart)
package:json_storage/main.dart:1
#1      HomeState.build
package:json_storage/main.dart:183
#2      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4691
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4574
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4746
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (23568): true
E/flutter (23568): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter (23568):
E/flutter (23568): ^
E/flutter (23568):
E/flutter (23568): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (23568): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:522:7)
E/flutter (23568): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:41:10)
E/flutter (23568): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter (23568): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter (23568): #5      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10)
E/flutter (23568): #6      HomeState.initState.<anonymous closure>
package:json_storage/main.dart:131
E/flutter (23568): #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (23568): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (23568): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23568):
```

He probado ya poniendolo async por si acaso pero parece que no es el problema, a si que no se que puede estar pasando.

Aqui dejo el codigo, es simplemente el archivo main.dart no tengo nada mas ya que es una app de prueba para ver si podia crear ese json y escribir en el, ademas he usado el paquete path_provider, pero eso es todo, puedo poner un repositorio en github si es necesario, pero solo es copiar y pegar este codigo y añadir path_provider en pubspec.yaml.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController keyInputController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController valueInputController = new TextEditingController();

  late File jsonFile;
  late Directory dir;
  String fileName = 'myJsonFile.json';
  bool fileExists = false;
  // Si usas otra cosa Pon String, dynamic
  late Map<String, dynamic> fileContent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((Directory directory) {
      dir = directory;
      jsonFile = new File(dir.path + '/' + fileName);
      jsonFile.createSync();
      fileExists = jsonFile.existsSync();
      print(fileExists);
      if (fileExists) {
        fileContent = jsonDecode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    keyInputController.dispose();
    valueInputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void createFile(Map<String, String> content, Directory dir, String fileName) {
    print('Creating file!');
    File file = new File(dir.path + '/' + fileName);
    file.createSync();
    fileExists = true;
    file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(content));
  }

  void writeToFile(String key, String value) {
    print('Writing to file');
    Map<String, String> content = {key: value};
    if (fileExists) {
      print('File exists');
      Map<String, String> jsonFileContent =
          json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
      jsonFileContent.addAll(content);
      jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(jsonFileContent));
    } else {
      print('File does not exists!');
      createFile(content, dir, fileName);
    }
    this.setState(() {
      fileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("JSON Tutorial"),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text(
            "File content: ",
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          new Text((fileContent.toString() == '')
              ? 'PlaceHolder'
              : fileContent.toString()),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text("Add to JSON file: "),
          new TextField(
            controller: keyInputController,
          ),
          new TextField(
            controller: valueInputController,
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
          new ElevatedButton(
              child: new Text("Add key, value pair"),
              onPressed: () {
                writeToFile(keyInputController.text, valueInputController.text);
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Alguna idea de que puede pasar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vale, ya encontre mi fallo, el problema principal esque este codigo era con la version de Dart 1 y al tratar de adaptarlo a Dart 2 me encontre con el problema.
Lo que sucedia es que al crear el archivo json este esta vacio asi que al no tener ningun key, value, parece ser que se genera un Map<String, dynamic>, ya que en una de las pruebas que estaba haciendo me dio este error:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: HomeState#5f124):
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' of 'function result'
```

Entonces decidi cambiar mi fileContent de esto:

```
late Map<String, String> fileContent;
```

a esto:

```
late Map<String, dynamic> fileContent;
```

y lo cambie tambien en la funcion writeToFile de esto:

```
Map<String, String> jsonFileContent =
          json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
```

a esto:

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonFileContent =
          json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
```

Solo esos dos cambios arreglaron el problema ya que como dije al generarse el archivo al principio y estar vacio era de tipo Map<String, dynamic> o como mucho Map<dynamic, dynamic> pero no era Map<String, String> asi que fileContent no se podia inicializar ya que no se le añadia el valor que pide.

Espero que esto ayude a alguien y gracias por la ayuda a @h8moss que me estuvo ayudando en el canal ingles de stackoverflow y me dijo que el problema es que el archivo json estaba vacio al querer ponerlo como valor de fileContent, al final el problema si que venia porque el archivo estaba vacio, aunque no fuera simplemente por estar vacio sino por el tipo que retorna.